# Accepting form data from HTML in Python

Tags: javascript, python, html, twitter

I am trying to write a simple web app as a school assignment. Basically, the app uses the twitter stream API to pull tweets, and then I'm going  to graph the results using Google Charts.

I have written a python script that is able to make the connection to twitter and pull the tweets in real time, but I want to be able to define the search criteria based off of user input on an HTML page. (I don't have it written yet, but I plan to have a list of radio buttons that a user can select from to choose the search option)

My question is how do I import data from an HTML document into my python script, and then return the data back to my HTML page.

I am very new to python and web programming in general, so over simplification would be nice!

This is the code in my python file:

```
from tweepy import Stream
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
from tweepy.streaming import StreamListener
import time


ckey = ''
csecret = ''
atoken = ''
asecret = ''

class listener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self,data):
        try:

            tweet = data.split(',"text":"')[1].split('","source')[0]
            print tweet

            saveThis = str(time.time())+ '::' + tweet
            print saveThis

            saveFile = open ('twitDB.csv' , 'a')
            saveFile.write (saveThis)
            saveFile.write ('\n')
            saveFile.close()
            return True
        except BaseException, e:
            print 'failed ondata, ', str(e)
            time.sleep(5)

    def on_error(self,status):
        print status



auth =OAuthHandler(ckey,csecret)
auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

twitterStream = Stream(auth, listener())
twitterStream.filter(track=["car"])
```

Comment: You can use [Flask]() OR [Django]() web-frameworks for handling web requests and responses. Essentially, you will be generating HTML page as response to the requests submitted by user.

Comment: My apology (cant edit previous comment). You can use [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org) OR [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com) web-frameworks for handling web requests and responses. Essentially, you will be generating HTML page as response to the requests submitted by user.